# why are there colors and comparisons missing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using this command via [ggstatsplot](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/articles/web_only/ggbetweenstats.html):

```
ggbetweenstats(
  data = df_sub
  , x = Generator
  , y = hours
  , outlier.tagging  = TRUE
  , map_signif_level = TRUE
  , ggsignif.args    = list(textsize = 4, tip_length = 0.01)
  , results.subtitle = TRUE) + 
  theme_bw() +
  guides(fill=guide_legend("Class"))
```

and receive this plot:

[image: img]

which is fine, except that those three group levels to the right are missing data points and colors. In addition, some statistical comparisons/tests are missing, or? E.g., the one far to the right is compared only once.

I cropped the image slightly as the data is confidential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some discrete color scales only have just a few available colors. The default color scheme `hue` has more colors:

```
ggbetweenstats(
  data = df_sub,
  x = Generator, 
  y = hours,
  outlier.tagging  = TRUE,
  map_signif_level = TRUE,
  ggsignif.args    = list(textsize = 4, tip_length = 0.01),
  results.subtitle = TRUE
  ) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_hue() +
  guides(fill=guide_legend("Class")
```

To have more control over the tests to make you can just use the underlying packages `ggpubr` and `ggplot2`.

Comment: Thank you! In which way did I change the default color settings? I was expecting that it's not foreseen to have so many groups and the available colors just reached their end..

Comment: It is probably part of the `ggbetweenstats` function

Comment: @Ben Are you sure the function didn't warn you about choosing a different color palette? Because it does check and warn user about this (https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ggstatsplot/blob/b01747b16521031771662b13ba5c4112bb75a023/R/ggbetweenstats_helpers.R#L258). In this case, you can use `palette` and `package` parameters to select a different palette which has more colors available.